# Video mode in my app gives a fuzzy image

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturedevice

In my app I'm using iPhone's camera video mode to do some scanning. I implemented the scanner, but I noticed that in my app the video image is kind of fuzzy comparing to the video image of other apps when I use the same phone. Below are the image samples.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

My app:

[image]

iPhone camera app:
[image]

barcode scanner app:
[image]

Comment: Share some code with us. Perhaps it's something with configuration of capture mode or view that displays it

Comment: @Kubba: sorry, I have lots of files with bunch of code. But I just figured it out. I had to manually set:   sessionPreset to AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080